# Joining polygons to points returns no rows?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, point, spatial-join, vector-grid

I'm trying to join a 1000m fishnet grid to a layer of points, so that for each point I can find out which grid cell the point lies in. Both the grid and points layers are saved in a file Geodatabase. However, when I run join by location (falls within) it tells me that the "Join was successful, but the resulting table has no rows." Why is this happening and what can I do?

Below are screenshots of the points against the grid, as well as the attribute tables of the grid and points respectively:

[image: points against grid]

Points against grid

[image: grid attribute table]

Grid attribute table

[image: points attribute table]

Points attribute table

[image: outcome of join]

Outcome of join

Comment: Yes they have the same reference system (EPSG:5880). How is it possible that join doesn't work though? It's clear from the screenshot that the points all lie within the grid :(

Answer (score 0):

Polygons cant fall inside points. Try joining the points to the polygons instead.

Comment: I think that's for counting the number of points inside each polygon - I'm trying to match each point to the polygon it falls in.

Comment: Intersect - Summary statistics